# wxstring undefined reference

Tags: wxwidgets, undefined-reference

I'm getting undefined reference upon linking a program using wxgtk. I tried suggestions from other places like defining unicode macro and --no-as-needed, but neither has fixed the problem. These are examples of the errors from the linker:

```
undefined reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
undefined reference to `wxString::mb_str(wxMBConv const&) const'
undefined reference to `operator+(wchar_t const*, wxString const&)'
```

This is the line used to link:

```
/usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o Aria -pthread -Wl,
  -rpath,/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib -Wl,
  --rpath,/mnt/utmp/aria/lib/ rtmidi/RtMidi.o irrXML/irrXML.o 
  ibjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_smpte.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_edittrack.o 
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_process.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_fileshow.o
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_showcontrolhandler.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_matrix.o
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_midi.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_file.o 
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_advancedsequencer.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_filewrite.o 
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_showcontrol.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_filereadmultitrack.o 
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_sequencer.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_multitrack.o 
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_tick.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_queue.o 
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_manager.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_filewritemultitrack.o 
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_track.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_msg.o 
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_tempo.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_fileread.o 
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_driverdump.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_keysig.o       
  libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_parser.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_driver.o libjdkmidi/src/jdkmidi_sysex.o libjdkmidi/src/win32/jdkmidi_driverwin32.o Src/LeakCheck.o Src/PresetManager.o Src/UnitTest.o Src/PreferencesData.o Src/UnitTestUtils.o Src/AriaCore.o Src/Clipboard.o Src/languages.o Src/main.o Src/Singleton.o Src/Editors/ScoreEditor.o Src/Editors/RelativeXCoord.o Src/Editors/ControllerEditor.o Src/Editors/KeyboardEditor.o Src/Editors/DrumEditor.o Src/Editors/GuitarEditor.o Src/Editors/Editor.o Src/Dialogs/AboutDialog.o Src/Dialogs/TrackPropertiesDialog.o Src/Dialogs/TuningDialog.o Src/Dialogs/PresetEditor.o Src/Dialogs/Preferences.o Src/Dialogs/CustomKeyDialog.o Src/Dialogs/CopyrightWindow.o Src/Dialogs/CustomNoteSelectDialog.o Src/Dialogs/WaitWindow.o Src/Dialogs/ScaleDialog.o Src/Dialogs/PrintSetupDialog.o Src/Midi/InstrumentChoice.o Src/Midi/GuitarTuning.o Src/Midi/ControllerEvent.o Src/Midi/KeyPresets.o Src/Midi/MeasureData.o Src/Midi/DrumChoice.o Src/Midi/Track.o Src/Midi/MagneticGrid.o Src/Midi/Sequence.o Src/Midi/CommonMidiUtils.o Src/Midi/Note.o Src/Midi/TimeSigChange.o Src/Midi/Players/PlatformMidiManager.o Src/Midi/Players/NullDevice.o Src/Midi/Players/Sequencer.o Src/Midi/Players/Alsa/AlsaPlayer.o Src/Midi/Players/Alsa/AlsaPort.o Src/Midi/Players/Alsa/AlsaNotePlayer.o Src/Midi/Players/Mac/OutputBase.o Src/Midi/Players/Mac/MacPlayerInterface.o Src/Midi/Players/Mac/CoreMIDIOutput.o Src/Midi/Players/Mac/AudioUnitOutput.o Src/Midi/Players/Example/ExamplePlayer.o Src/Midi/Players/Jack/JackMidiManager.o Src/Midi/Players/Win/WinPlayer.o Src/IO/MidiFileReader.o Src/IO/IOUtils.o Src/IO/AriaFileWriter.o Src/IO/MidiToMemoryStream.o Src/Analysers/SilenceAnalyser.o Src/Analysers/ScoreAnalyser.o Src/Actions/DeleteTrack.o Src/Actions/SnapNotesToGrid.o Src/Actions/ScaleSong.o Src/Actions/Duplicate.o Src/Actions/RearrangeNotes.o Src/Actions/ShiftBySemiTone.o Src/Actions/InsertEmptyMeasures.o Src/Actions/RemoveOverlapping.o Src/Actions/Record.o Src/Actions/Paste.o Src/Actions/EditAction.o Src/Actions/ResizeNotes.o Src/Actions/MoveNotes.o Src/Actions/AddControllerSlide.o Src/Actions/SetAccidentalSign.o Src/Actions/AddTrack.o Src/Actions/UpdateGuitarTuning.o Src/Actions/AddNote.o Src/Actions/ScaleTrack.o Src/Actions/RemoveMeasures.o Src/Actions/DeleteSelected.o Src/Actions/SetNoteVolume.o Src/Actions/ShiftFrets.o Src/Actions/ShiftString.o Src/Actions/NumberPressed.o Src/Actions/AddControlEvent.o Src/Pickers/MagneticGridPicker.o Src/Pickers/VolumeSlider.o Src/Pickers/KeyPicker.o Src/Pickers/TuningPicker.o Src/Pickers/ControllerChoice.o Src/Pickers/TimeSigPicker.o Src/Pickers/InstrumentPicker.o Src/Pickers/NotePickerWidget.o Src/Pickers/DrumPicker.o Src/Renderers/wxImage.o Src/Renderers/AbstractDrawable.o Src/Renderers/wxDrawable.o Src/Renderers/wxRenderPane.o Src/Renderers/GLImage.o Src/Renderers/GLwxString.o Src/Renderers/GLDrawable.o Src/Renderers/GLRenderImp.o Src/Renderers/GLPane.o Src/Renderers/wxRenderImp.o Src/Renderers/wxDCString.o Src/Printing/wxEasyPrintWrapper.o Src/Printing/KeyrollPrintableSequence.o Src/Printing/AbstractPrintableSequence.o Src/Printing/AriaPrintable.o Src/Printing/RenderRoutines.o Src/Printing/SymbolPrinter/TabPrint.o Src/Printing/SymbolPrinter/ScorePrint.o Src/Printing/SymbolPrinter/EditorPrintable.o Src/Printing/SymbolPrinter/SymbolPrintableSequence.o Src/Printing/SymbolPrinter/PrintLayout/LayoutElement.o Src/Printing/SymbolPrinter/PrintLayout/RelativePlacementManager.o Src/Printing/SymbolPrinter/PrintLayout/PrintLayoutAbstract.o Src/Printing/SymbolPrinter/PrintLayout/PrintLayoutLine.o Src/Printing/SymbolPrinter/PrintLayout/PrintLayoutNumeric.o Src/Printing/SymbolPrinter/PrintLayout/PrintLayoutMeasure.o Src/GUI/MainPane.o Src/GUI/ImageProvider.o Src/GUI/GraphicalSequence.o Src/GUI/MainFrame.o Src/GUI/MainFrameMenuBar.o Src/GUI/MeasureBar.o Src/GUI/GraphicalTrack.o
-L/mnt/utmp/aria/lib -L/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib
-Lmnt/utmp/aria/lib -Lmnt/utmp/aria/lib -L/opt/gnome/lib 
-lwx_gtk2u_core-2.8-arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi 
-lwx_baseu-2.8-arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi -lasound -ldl -lm -lglib-2.0
```

Rearranging the link params didn't change the result and it seems the two wx libs used in the linker should be the two used.

Answer (score 0):

wxString is in the library wxBase.

You are linking to

```
-lwx_baseu-2.8-arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
```

which I assume is the wxBase library.

Can you link the sample programs?  ( *Answer: yes* )  So, please post the link command you are using to build one of the samples, for comparison with the failing link command.

Taking a look at your 'sample' link command line, I notice that the sample is being compiled with the non-unicode version of the libraries, whereas the failing link is using the unicode version.  I suggest trying to build the samples using unicode, and the test program without - the results should be informative.

```
-lwx_base_xml-2.8-arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
-lexpat -lwx_gtk2_adv-2.8-arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
-lwx_gtk2_html-2.8-arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
-lwx_gtk2_core-2.8-arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi 
-lwx_base-2.8-arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
```

The sample uses **-lwx_base_xml-2.8-arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi** but you use **-lwx_baseu-2.8-arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi** Have you tried changing that?

Comment: linking the samples programs seems to work fine. Here's the link line from the widgets example when it ran.
http://pastebin.com/Ucn6YQE4

Comment: changing the link to use the unicode also completes fine.
http://pastebin.com/MnPeBeSd
Interesting thing is when compiling wxgtk, I specify to make unicode. Not sure where the non-unicode is coming from.

Comment: the base_xml is a different lib than base. Here's the list of libs I compiled:
http://pastebin.com/gS9eiFs3